# api service with retrofit and reactivex observable

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

if i have 4 api service request using retrofit and i call all of them in my activity, do the 2nd waiting 1st one to finish or 2nd or 3rd requested without waiting other to complete,
here myapi servise list:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("goes/for/api1")
Observable<ResponseBody> req1(
        @HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers,
        @FieldMap Map<String, String> fields);

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("goes/for/api2")
Observable<ResponseBody> req2(
        @HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers,
        @FieldMap Map<String, String> fields);

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("goes/for/api3")
Observable<ResponseBody> req3(
        @HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers,
        @FieldMap Map<String, String> fields);

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("goes/for/api4")
Observable<ResponseBody> req4(
        @HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers,
        @FieldMap Map<String, String> fields);
```

request on presenter:

```
public void request1(){
   Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
   headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
   Map<String, String> fields = new HashMap<>();
   fields.put("key", "value");
   Observable<ResponseBody> response = mApiService.req1(headers, fields);
   subscribe(response, this);
}
public void request2(){
   Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
   headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
   Map<String, String> fields = new HashMap<>();
   fields.put("key", "value");
   Observable<ResponseBody> response = mApiService.req2(headers, fields);
   subscribe(response, this);
}
public void request3(){
   Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
   headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
   Map<String, String> fields = new HashMap<>();
   fields.put("key", "value");
   Observable<ResponseBody> response = mApiService.req3(headers, fields);
   subscribe(response, this);
}
public void request4(){
   Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
   headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
   Map<String, String> fields = new HashMap<>();
   fields.put("key", "value");
   Observable<ResponseBody> response = mApiService.req4(headers, fields);
   subscribe(response, this);
}
```

my presenter handle and deliver response to activity

```
@Override
public void onNext(ResponseBody responseBody) {
    try {
        getView().onDeliverResponse(responseBody.string());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

for every call i make a state request
`String state = "state1"`

```
@Override
public void onDeliverResponse(String response) {
    handleResponse(response);
}

void handleResponse(String response) {
   if(state = "state1"){
     //
   }
   else {
     //
   }
}
```

my state string will override to my last request `"state4"`, so state is become "state4" when 3rd request complete? cos every request will update my ui

Comment: If I correctly understand you, you want to wait for 1st request to finish and then start 2nd request ? And what about 3nd and 4th requests I didn't understand

Comment: sorry if my question make u confuse, i'm making state for every request, state will override to my last request(4th req will overrride state to "state4") cos i'm call all void please see updated....

Comment: Ok, I am still a little confused, I understood your code. You update state in activity from presenter after each request finishes. Sometimes the request might finish in different order than you called them . And What is the problem ?

Comment: is onNext will call sequence or it could be override if take more time to get response result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you call those API requests separately of each other, you never know the sequence of OnNext methods call, because it depends on server response time. 
E.g. you may call those requests in sequense

**req1**

**req2**

**req3**

**req4**

But get states like this

**resp2**

**resp4**

**resp1**

**resp3**

So, your final state will be state3. If you want to have responses in sequence you should use RxJava operators, such as flatMap, or others:

```
apiService.A()
.doOnNext(modelA -> getView().updateState("state1"))
.flatMap(modelA -> apiService.B())
.doOnNext(modelb -> getView().updateState("state2"));
```

Example: 
https://medium.com/@adinugroho/chaining-multiple-retrofit-call-using-rxjava-177b64c8103e

Or call each observable in onNext(or onCompleted) of previous observable subscription.

Comment: thank you for your attention and answer i will vote your answer and do research for flatMap, and will accept soon

Comment: I've updated my answer for you to understand flatMap better, for your situation. Also if you have problem with flatmap, you can use second solution I wrote, also I've added exmaple